# Assigning styles to a form in Rails 4.1

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I have this box in this style and Rails 4.1:

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='controls with-icon-over-input'>
         <%= label_tag :email, 'Email :' %>
         <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
         <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

But I need this code to insert rails within the next style, just inside the :

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='controls with-icon-over-input'>
        <input value="" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" data-rule-required="true" name="email" type="text" />
        <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try the following permo way I do not get, I hope alquien can help me:

```
<div class='form-group'>
     <div class='controls with-icon-over-input'>
     <input value='<%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>' placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" data-rule-required="true" name="email" type="text" />
     <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails comes with built-in helpers to define html attributes. Look at the documentation and some examples [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='controls with-icon-over-input'>
         <%= label_tag :email, 'Email :' %>
         <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control', data: { rule_required: 'true' } %>
         <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

For [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) (looks like you are using it, in your comment) :

```
<%= f.input :email, input_html: 
                      { class: 'form-control', 
                        placeholder: 'Email', 
                        data:  { rule_required: 'true'} } %>
```

Comment: Excelent, and now if I want to insert dynamically within this syntax:      <%= f.input :login, :label => 'email' %>  As would the syntax ???

Comment: If you want to insert what... ?

Comment: <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], placeholder: 'Email', class: 'form-control', data: { rule_required: 'true' } %>       IN :        <%= f.input :login, :label => 'email' %>